# Asp.net mvc ajax call not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

my url is look  like :

localhost:1336/PartPicker/Part/Mobile/list_view

i want ajax post request. But ajax request is not wroking

my controller action code

```
 public JsonResult getProduct(String partid, String id)
    {
        return Json("success");
    }
```

my ajax request code

```
 function btn_Click()
    {
        var sdata = { partid: 'abc', id: 'xyz' };




        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'getProduct',
            data: JSON.stringify(sdata), 
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 
            dataType: "jsonp", 
            processdata: false, 
            success: function (data) { alert(data);},
            error: function (serverdata) { alert("eror " + serverdata.responseText) },
            async: false
        });


    }
```

route settings

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{partid}/{id}/",
            defaults: new
                        {
                            controller = "PartPicker",
                            action = "Part",
                            partid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional
                        },

                          namespaces: new[] { " abc.Controllers" }

                        );
```

I can't identify why ajax request is not working. Please someone help me

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting a client side error? A server side error? You need to be specific when you ask, because "not working" can mean many different things.

Comment: i think there is no client side error. server not accepting the request. when url is look like localhost:1336/PartPicker/Part it works perfectly....@mason

Comment: "Server not accepting the request". What does that mean? Is there an error message? If so, post it in your question. You *think* there is no client side error? Use your browser's debugging tools to verify.

Comment: I think problem is in url. because when url is like localhost:1336/PartPicker/Part it works. but when url is look like localhost:1336/PartPicker/Part/Mobile/list_view then request fail

Comment: Yes, you said that already. Use your browser's debugging tools to see if the request fails. Also try navigating directly to localhost:1336/PartPicker/Part/Mobile/list_view and see what the response is.

Comment: I have solved this problem........thanks   mason

Comment: Make sure you post your answer so others will know how you solved your problem. Or if Chandra's answer was the correct solution, hit the check mark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sdata = "{'partid':'abc','id':'xyz'}";
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer?